# zcat can assign as a variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, zcat

I will like to unzip several files and merge it as ONE variable in bash.

For example: 
There are several text files.

```
one=text1.gz
two=text2.gz
three=text3.gz
```

I would like to merge them to become a variable

```
variable=(zcat $one $two $three)
```

So

```
$variable=($one)+($two)+($three)
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is archived under `text1.gz`? Is it a folder or a list of files?

Comment: @Inian as far as I know, gzip zips only single files. I think you are confused with tarballs.

Answer (score 0):

You bash syntax isn't correct.

To assign a variable the result of the command, you need to use `$(...)`:

```
variable=$(zcat "$one" "$two" "$three")
```

Depending on what you want to do with the content of these files, this might not be the best way forward.

You might want concatenate the files into another one using redirection:

```
zcat "$one" "$two" "$three" > combined_file
```

then work with the `combine_file`.

Or directly process command further using pipe `|`:

```
zcat "$one" "$two" "$three" | my_command
```

where `my_command` could be `sed`, `awk`, etc...

Comment: You also need to quote the command substitution to preserve the new lines

Comment: @Inian Not exactly. You need to use the quoted variable like this `"$variable"` to preserve newlines. Doing `variable="$(...)"` is not necessary. Or do I miss something?

Comment: I guess its ok in this context, but in the content of the `variable` the lack of quotes will cause trouble if it contains whitespace or globbing characters